# How to include native assets with a .Net Core 2.0 console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I would like to know if there's a supported method to include native libraries for specific runtime identifiers with a .net core console application so that after publishing the app the correct native library for the current is loaded via PInvoke when the app is run.

At least for nuget packages there seems to be a way because after publishing my app which references the [libuv](https://github.com/aspnet/libuv-package) package, `app.deps.json` contains this:

```
"Libuv/1.10.0": {
  "runtimeTargets": {
    "runtimes/linux-arm/native/libuv.so": {
      "rid": "linux-arm",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/linux-arm64/native/libuv.so": {
      "rid": "linux-arm64",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/linux-armel/native/libuv.so": {
      "rid": "linux-armel",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/linux-x64/native/libuv.so": {
      "rid": "linux-x64",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/osx/native/libuv.dylib": {
      "rid": "osx",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/win-arm/native/libuv.dll": {
      "rid": "win-arm",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/win-x64/native/libuv.dll": {
      "rid": "win-x64",
      "assetType": "native"
    },
    "runtimes/win-x86/native/libuv.dll": {
      "rid": "win-x86",
      "assetType": "native"
    }
  }
},
```

In theory this would be exactly what I need for the app, yet I do not have any idea how to get `dotnet publish` to produce it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?